# help for icloud

Tags: iphone

My user id has change on my apple support but on my phone the apple user is still the old id. The user id for old apple id does not exist anymore. How can I delete the iCloud (apple id) on my phone and replace with the new apple id?

Answer (score 1):

Open the settings app, Scroll down to iCloud and tap it.  At the bottom of the screen is a button that says Delete Account.  Tap it.

You can now add a different one.